# TortoiseGit hiding commit popup

Tags: tortoise-svn, tortoise-git

I know an easy question but couldn't find the answer with Googling.

I use Tortoisegit 1.8.3, when I make a commit from Right mouse Context menu classical menu opens. When I click Commit a popup window opens and gives information about progress and result.

Is it possible to disable this popup, or autoclose in some seconds ?

Comment: In TortoiseSVN under `Settings / Dialogs 1 / Misc` you have the [Autoclose option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/haPnF.png). In a screenshot I found online of TortoiseGit, under `Settings / Dialogs / Misc` the [Autoclose option seems to be missing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O1PtC.png). Check in your version if tthat's still the case.

Comment: My version of TortoiseGit is same as your scrrenshot. No autoclose option.

Comment: Apparently the feature [wasn't implemented](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=80) more than 4 years back, and for some strange reason is [still missing](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=827).

Comment: Hmm strange situation..

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of TortoiseGit you can set the AutoClose option:

[image: Screenshot]

See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html